# Как сделать выборку товаров c фильтрацией по связных таблицах при связи многие ко многим?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

Есть таблица с товарами goods. Она связана с таблицей categories (многие ко многим), также с таблицей goods_filter_value (многие ко многим). Как сделать выборку при заданом alias категории и масива фильтров?
Сейчас делаю так:

```
protected function getProducts($alias, $filters = [])
    {
        $products = $this
            ->p_rep
            ->model
            ->select(
                'goods.name', 
                'goods.price',
                'goods.alias',
                'goods.discount_price',
                'goods.isNew', 
                'images.path'
                )
            ->join('images', 'goods.id', '=', 'images.product_id')
            ->join('goods_category', 'goods_category.product_id', '=', 'goods.id')
            ->join('categories', 'goods_category.category_id', '=', 'categories.id');

            if(count($filters) > 0 ){
                $products = $products->join('goods_filter_value', 'goods_filter_value.product_id', '=', 'goods.id')
                    ->join('values_filters', 'goods_filter_value.value_id', '=', 'values_filters.id')
                    ->whereIn('values_filters.id', $filters);
            }

            $products = $products->where('categories.alias', $alias)            
                ->where('images.isMain', 1)
                ->distinct()
                ->orderBy('goods.created_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate(\Config::get('settings.count_products_on_page'), ['goods.*']);

        return $products;
    }
```

проблема в том что когда я применяю больше фильтров, результатов становится больше а не наоборот +есть проблема с total в пагинации из за distinct

Comment: *когда я применяю больше фильтров, результатов становится больше* Значит, используете "ИЛИ" вместо "И".

Comment: c этим я разобрался, все дело у whereIn которое использует or, как изменить на and не соображу

Answer (score 1):

У меня аналогичная структура. Таблицы: goods, goods__attributes, attributes__values и attributes. Goods и attributes__values связаны многие-ко-многим через goods__attributes.
Запрос для множественного фильтра (когда у одного товара, к примеру, может быть несколько размеров) получился такой:

```
$goodList = Good::select('goods.*')
                ->when( $request->query(), function($query, $request){

                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
                        $query->join('goods__attributes as ga'.++$i, function ($join) use ($value, $i) {
                            $join->on('ga'.$i.'.good_id', '=', 'goods.id')
                                 ->whereIn('ga'.$i.'.attribute_value_id', $value);
                        });
                    }

                    $query->groupBy('goods.id');

                    return $query;
                })
                ->get();
```

В `$request->query()` падает запрос `[фильтр=>[id значений],...]`, например:

```
[
    'color' => [1],
    'size'  => [3,6],
]
```